# add event to a button inside li using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of products, each `<li>` has a delete button and product's name
so for deleting the product i should affect a function to the created buttons i tried many methods but it did'nt work by using javascript file 
but when i wrote the same code on the console of my navigator it works
so please tell me what's wrong
here is me jvascript code and html 
thank you

```js
var products = [];

//adding a prodicts
var button = document.querySelector("#add");
var name;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  name = prompt("donner le type du produit");
  products.push(name);
  var ul = document.getElementById("products");
  $("ul").append("<li><button class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>" + name + "</li>");

});
//deleting a product using java script

/*var deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName(".delete");
for (var i = 0 ; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
    deleteButton[i].addEventListener("click",function(){alert("you can delete this product now");}) ; 
 }
 
$(".delete").click(function(){alert("succ");});*/
$(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function() {

    alert("you can delete it now");
  });
});
```

```css
.form-inline {
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.delete {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover button {
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Résumé</button>
      <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Ajouter</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Aide</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">A propos</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<ul id="products">

</ul>
```

Comment: This answer should help you: [**Event binding on dynamic elements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements#answer-1207393)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change the way you attach event listener to the buttons. Because you are attaching event listener the buttons that are not preset in the DOM tree at that time, therefore there is not any event listener on those buttons.

Below is the code to attach an event listener to the elements which are not necessarily available in the DOM tree

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".delete",function() {

    alert("you can delete it now");
  });
});
```

This little change will solve your problem for event listeners

Comment: Instead of bloating document with listeners, you could assign a listener to the button at creation point. - And BTW this was already answered (suggested)

Comment: but if you have many logics to put the elements on the page then you have to attach event listeners everytime, so it is better to run a code once for all the elements in preset and future.

Comment: You're right. Say in the case that UL is already filled with LI. - but in the case that the list is dynamically generated from an array resource you can again assign events to the buttons -directly, without going down do `document`.

Comment: I just gave an exampe using document, you can do it with any static parent node actually.

Comment: I'd rather use a static parent ID in such case. I'm not the downoter. And Sandro gave the same suggestion 9min before you did. So probably that's the cause...

Answer (score 0):

Try this with method `.on`

```js
var products = [];

//adding a prodicts
var button = document.querySelector("#add");
var name;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  name = prompt("donner le type du produit");
  products.push(name);
  var ul = document.getElementById("products");
  $("ul").append("<li><button class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>" + name + "</li>");

});
//deleting a product using java script

/*var deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName(".delete");
for (var i = 0 ; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
    deleteButton[i].addEventListener("click",function(){alert("you can delete this product now");}) ; 
 }
 
$(".delete").click(function(){alert("succ");});*/
$(function() {
  $("body").on('click', '.delete', function() {

    alert("you can delete it now");
  });
});
```

```css
.form-inline {
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.delete {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover button {
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Résumé</button>
      <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Ajouter</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Aide</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">A propos</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<ul id="products">

</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write event Listener function inside either jquery ready function or javascript onload function to make it work properly.

So your delete function should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function() {
        alert("you can delete it now");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add event listeners for dynamic elements using jQuery, using `.on`

In your case, change `.click` to `.on` :

```
$(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function() {

    alert("you can delete it now");
  });
});
```

To:

```
$(function() {
  $(".delete").on('click', function() {

    alert("you can delete it now");
  });
});
```

`.on` vs `.click`: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: I suggest you to read the official documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ - specially the part on dynamic event delegation. The way you portrayed it is useless.